# Form::Helper cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Como que eu faço um for para retornar neste options 48 semanas?

```
<?= $this->Form->input('Semanas', array(
      'options' => $semanas,
      'empty' => '(choose one)'
 )); ?>
```

Comment: Teria como mostrar sua controller ?

Comment: Você quer mostras essas semanas como? Em números mesmo?

Comment: Queria mostrar "1 Semana", "2 semanas", etc..

Comment: A resposta deve ser salva como o número de semanas também é isso? Um *option* assim `<option value="1 semana">1 semana</option>`. Seria isso?

Comment: Sim, a resposta é o numero, e o argumento seria o numero + semana(s)

Answer (score 0):

No *Controller*, você pode ter algo assim, supondo que sua *action* seja a própria `index()`:

```
public function index() {
    $semanas = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 49; $i++) {
        $semanas[$i] = "$i semana" . ($i > 1 ? "s" : "");
    }

    $this->set('semanas', $semanas);
}
```

E a *View* permanece como está, assim o valor de cada opção será numérico correspondendo ao número da semana e o texto como você mencionou: 1 semana, 2 semanas, 3 semanas...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um for para popular um *array*, tanto no controller como voi mensionado, quanto na view assim:

### Assim:

```
<?php 
$semanas = array();
for($i=1;$i<49;$i++){
    $semanas["{$i} semanas"] = "{$i} semanas";
}
echo $this->Form->input('Semanas', array(
    'options' => $semanas,
    'empty' => '(choose one)'
)); ?>
```